# How to optimize mysql queries on a homepage news feed for fast results?

Tags: mysql, database, feed

I have a website with a homepage which shows the news feed with all kind of posts like events, meetups, or any article. So these posts are stored in different mysql tables depending on the kind of post.
Right now, i am simply getting the data from all these tables(which also have two-three JOINS) one by one , 10 posts each. But now since my data has increased alot so the performance has slowed down due to all the JOINS.

So is there any efficient way to deal with all the data and fetch them with no slow down? How do most news websites work with no lag in the performance?

I was thinking of creating virtual table in the database with all the results combined together(with joins and union) in a single table. All I have to do at the time of fetch, I just have to select query from the virtual table. So is my idea correct or is there any other way around?

**Update**:
Mockup Query:

```
select a.*, b.* from events as a
join users as b on a.userid = b.id
join groups as c on a.id = c.eventid
join likes as d on a.id = d.eventid
where a.created_at > [some-x-date]
and c.group IN (..,..,..)
group by a.id
order by a.created_at desc
```

There are 3 queries like these from 3 other tables. Even with indexing, this is creating a lag. Please suggest.

Comment: can someone please help me with this before directly down-voting my query? atleast tell me what am I missing? a query is a query. I think these platforms are meant to help people , no matter how stupid it might seem. not everyone is intelligent

Comment: The problem you are getting downvoted for is not providing enough information. You just said - "Some query, which I am not going to show you, is slow... What is wrong?" Which is literally impossible to guess at. Show us your query, and the code that uses it, and how many rows etc. in the tables. If this was so easy as there is a one answer, then consultants would not have jobs

Comment: well this is the thing. I am not very much into asking questions. Did alot of research before posting it. so thanks for letting me know what was wrong. I will updated with queries right away

Answer (score 0):

A Virtual Table (or view), will have the exact same (or maybe even slightly worse) performance as running the query itself.

Performance troubleshooting is a large topic, and without seeing any of your code (both backend, and SQL) there is no way we can guess why this is slow.

I would suggest looking at;

1 - Caching results if they do not need to be exactly up-to-date

2 - Review Indexing on the tables to make sure they have supporting indexes

3 - Check the backend code interfaces with the database correctly

EDIT AFTER POSTING QUERY:

Okay so a number of issues here;

```
select a.*, b.* from events as a
join users as b on a.userid = b.id
join groups as c on a.id = c.eventid
join likes as d on a.id = d.eventid
where a.created_at > [some-x-date]
and c.group IN (..,..,..)
group by a.id
order by a.created_at desc
```

You are selecting **all fields** from a and b, but also grouping by a.id - This doesn't really make sense to me... It will also not allow indexes to be used effectively as all fields will be pulled out. Do you really need all the fields?? And why do you use a groupby?

Is there an index on a.userid, a.created_at and c.group?

Comment: Dear Milney, thanks for replying. I havent posted any code because i felt this is a conceptual thing. My concepts are not clear on how to implement this without any performance lag. Caching is a secondary thing and will work only once. I still have to get updated data if the user keeps scrolling down. Indexing is already done but still there is lag. and i will re-design the backend code once i am clear how to efficiently design my DB. Are you sure querying from multiple tables with 3 joins in a single request is right?

Comment: @Tani Yes joins are a natural part of Database Queries and can perform very well assuming the correct indexes are in place... This is certainly not conceptual, and the actual SQL code and the code of the indexes will heavily influence the performance. If you want an answer you will simply have to post code. The mere fact you think joins may be the problem points to a misunderstanding of how the database works and therefore probably incorrect indexes being used or a overly heavy query

Comment: I have posted the code. also assuming that my concepts on joins might be wrong, i will read more into it. But is this how most websites work on activity feed? query from multiple tables at the runtime?

Comment: this query is just a mock-up. only to show the number of joins and how many are used. please my question is not where my query is going wrong because the real query is pretty perfect. my sole question is JOINS at runtime is the only answer?

Comment: @Tani - How do you know it is "pretty perfect"? If you need data from all those tables, then yes you need that many joins - but in your example you join to the [likes] table and then don't use it. As I said, if you don't post your real query, noone can answer it. The number of Joins is irrelevant and will not make your query go slow themselves, bad indexing and incorrect sql will. You didn't reply if you had any indexes so I assume that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to optimize your queries - you can post specific SQL and EXPLAINs here. In general terms, on modern hardware, SQL databases can handle millions of rows without trouble. Joins do not cause notable performance problems if you can use indexes. There are usually challenges once you get to a large number of concurrent users; this typically requires caching and/or lazy loading (see below).

Looking at your mock up query, there is no reason why this should be slow - the joins are on primary and foreign keys, and the where clause uses highly indexable columns. I'd expect this to return in fractions of a second with (tens of) millions of rows in all tables on modern hardware.

In the comment, you mention that the page has slowed down now that you've got a lot of traffic. The easiest and cheapest solution is to buy more hardware - additional RAM for your database server, a faster hard disk. You are almost certainly hitting some kind of hardware bottleneck, and if your database queries are optimal, it's unlikely denormalizing will make a big impact.

High traffic website use a lot of caching, so instead of retrieving the news from the database for each page request, they will cache the results. This can improve performance and scalability dramatically - pretty much every web framework has a caching solution.

Configuring caches is a question of judgement and experimentation - you have to trade performance and scalability agains "freshness". If your peak load is 1000 concurrent users / minute, caching data base queries for 1 minute reduces the load on your database by 999 requests, at the expense of a 1 minute "freshness" delay. That may well be acceptable.

You can also build a solution where publishing a new news article flushes the cache, and the first request after the flush rebuilds it; all subsequent requests read the cache until it's flushed again. This improves "freshness", at the expense of 1 potentially slower page request.

Thirdly, "lazy loading": high performance websites tend to fetch content asynchronously, using AJAX or similar. At a super simplistic level, they'll serve you static HTML with the boxes for the news feed with placeholders, and run asynchronous Javascript calls to replace the placeholders as the data returns. Typically, "lazy loading" only loads the content that's visible to the user (thus reducing both the number of queries and the amount of data loaded into the page).

Comment: Thanks for replying @Neville. My lag arose when suddenly alot of data and traffic increased on the page. you mentioned, we can cache results for each page requests. wont it give old data since an activity feed is based on latest post? Also lazy loading is a good idea, will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If your lag increased due to data size, you can almost certainly optimize your queries. If it's due to traffic, you need to find ways to protect your database, e.g. by caching.